# How to properly type component props? Type X is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Y'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, react-props

I have a component that accepts `data` with type `PropsT`, but TypeScript is throwing an error
Type '{ data: { title: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsT'.
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsT'.

```
type PropsT = [
  { title: string }
]
const ChildComp = (data: PropsT) => {
  return <>{data[0].title}</>
}
```

Comment: error speaks for itself, you should pass title prop not data, try something like this: <ChildComp title="someText" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two problems:

```
const ChildComp = (data: PropsT) => {
```

Here, `data` is the props given. It's an object. You probably meant to destructure this:

```
const ChildComp = ({ data }: PropsT) => {
```

The props type `PropsT` should reflect this:

```
type PropsT = {
    data: { title: string; }[];
};
```

Another change was `[{ title: string }]` to `{ title: string }[]`.

The former is a tuple with only one element, while the latter is an array.
Tuples have fixed lengths while arrays can have as many elements as it wants.